# Why did Albert Einstein receive a nobel prize?

Tags: history, photoelectric-effect

We all know that he received the prize due to his explanation of photoelectric effect. But the photoelectric effect, it’s a mere 3-4 page topic and uses a simple equation that typically anyone can derive.

Is that all Einstein did? Or is the Photoelectric explanation much more than this equation-[image]

Comment: Given that nobody before had figured out the 'simple' effect, and you have a hundred years of physics to look back over, perhaps you should rethink the tone of your question.

Comment: It's often said that he really won it for relativity, but because relativity hadn't yet been confirmed, he was awarded it for the photoelectric effect.    I find it hard to believe that there isn't some truth to that, though, I also agree with the 2 points made.  The discovery of the photoelectric effect is an underappreciated discovery in science.   But I'm not sure he'd have won the prize for that if he hadn't followed that with relativity.

Comment: You could say that Einstein did three or four times in a row the most obvious thing that any theoretical physicist could have done with the known data available to them. That's like three hole-in-ones in golf, if you forgive my analogy. Everybody can go to the course, everybody can hit the little white ball. How many will manage to achieve such a sequence of "trivial" results?

Comment: @userLTK: I don't think there were any doubts about special relativity in 1921 anymore and the general theory of relativity had been confirmed twice: with the proper prediction of the Mercury perihelion drift and with Eddington's observation of deflection of starlight by the sun, which happened in 1919. The next confirmation of general relativity wouldn't come until Hubble's discovery in 1922/23 (published in peer reviewed papers in 1925) and the precision experiments in general relativity didn't begin until after Einstein's death, I believe.

Comment: "Research is to see what everybody else has seen, and to think what nobody else has thought"-Albert Szent gyorgyi

Comment: About "We all know that...": _Prize motivation: "for his services to Theoretical Physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect"_ http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1921/einstein-facts.html Also there are two missing words and two typos in the picture that you've attached.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the motivations of the Nobel commitee, not an objective question about physics.

Comment: This question should be migrated to [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for HSM, as it's entirely opinion-based. Trying to defend the importance of Einstein's work on the photoelectric effect is not for a historian.

Answer (score 10):

What Einstein added to the discussion was the idea that electromagnetic energy comes in little particle-like packets.  That was a very radical concept at the time (and frankly still is).

Comment: Planck discovered/introduced quanta in 1900.

Comment: @Geremia: and Plank's paper kind of implied that it was an ad-hoc assumption to make the blackbody spectrum work.  Einstein's photoelectric effect was the first to elevate this to a general property of light.

Comment: @Geremia Planck told the world the black bodies must emit light in little packets. Einstein showed that not only heat radiation is emitted in packets, but it and every other electromagnetic wave travels and is absorbed in packets. Being in these packets is a fundamental property of light. No one knew that before, it was assumed that blackbody might emit packets of light, but they become continuous when travelling and interacting with stuff.

Answer (score -8):

Millikan was the first to experimentally discover the photoelectric effect. The [1923 Physics Nobel Prize](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1923/) was awarded to Millikan "for his work on the elementary charge of electricity and on the photoelectric effect". Einstein did no experimental work regarding the photoelectric effect.

Also, the [1918 Nobel Prize](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1918/planck-facts.html) was awarded to Max Plank "in recognition of the services he rendered to the advancement of Physics by his discovery of energy quanta," which they say he discovered in 1900. According to [the description of Einstein's Nobel Prize](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1921/einstein-facts.html), "in 1905, Albert Einstein explained that light consists of quanta - 'packets' with fixed energies corresponding to certain frequencies."

Einstein's Physics Nobel Prize is probably the most controversial one ever given. The historian of science and author of [*Albert Einstein: The Incorrigible Plagiarist*](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/49610960) (2002), Christopher Jon Bjerknes, concludes his freely-available 2,825 page *magnum opus*, *[The Manufacture and Sale of Saint Einstein](https://archive.org/download/ChristopherJonBjerknesTheManufactureAndSaleOfSaintEinstein/SaintEinstein.pdf)*, with the well-documented chapter "19. Albert Einstein's Nobel Prize" (p. 2,386), which describes the politics behind Einstein Nobel Prize.

Comment: Could the down-voters please comment?

Comment: Christopher Jon Bjerknes is neither a historian nor a scientist.  He's a neo-nazi, racist wack-job.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix So? He's done some very thorough, well-documented research.